# How to efficiently analyse frame drops in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, xcode7

I am working on a game for iOS 9+ using SpriteKit framework and Xcode 7.3.1. Currently my app suffers slight frame drops from 60 to about 57  from time to time without a clear pattern; which causes nasty glitches. First I thought it happens due to audio effects I am playing, but it's definitely not the only cause.

What instruments and technique would you recommend me to further analyse this problem?

It would be nice to see a hierarchy of the called functions in all threads at the point in time the frame rate drops. I know from other IDE's that there exist analyser tools that show time consumption for individual function calls. Is there anything similar for Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you want is Instruments. Use the "Core Animation" template, which will have the two instruments you want ("Core Animation" and "Time Profiler").

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm quite new to iOS and X-Code. Exactly what I was looking for :-)